# In Box2d i got 2349 errors when i chang code from one mac to other mac

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working on Box2d application,

my problem is when i move my application's source code from one mac to another mac i got 2349 Errors, i don't know why i am getting this errors.

i even try removing Box2D source from my application from and add again but doesn't work.

if any one know reason and solution please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my Question.

i got such errors because of change in name of my projects containing folder.

i.e. my working project was at source path /Bubbles/Boxes 
on destination mac i changed it to /Bubbles123/Boxes

i changed Bubbles to Bubbles123 that was the problem, it might be creating problem with path.

it works for me now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing some framework. Posting some of the error messages might help us to help you better!

Comment: @Qiau : hi, Thanks. i get lots of errors most of them are /Box2D/Box2D.h:34:37: error: Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Qiau : i am using http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/physics-101-uikit-app-with-box2d-for-gravity/ tutorial. all the error are from Box2d's group foulder.

Comment: Yes, the project cannot find the Box2D files. Try to update the project settings again according to the start of the tutorial, from the paragraph that begins with "Box2D uses angle brackets for all imports..".

Comment: @Qiau : but i had already replace with new file's from Box2d. how can i find solution?

Comment: .. also, if you didn't check "Copy item(s) into destination's group folder" when you imported Box2D, the files are not included in the project. And therefore will not follow you to another computer if you only copy the project.

Comment: @Qiau : Let me try following tutorial again in to my existing project.